# Message Tone is not working

Tags: 8.1, ringtone, messaging, developer-preview

I'm using Windows Phone 8.1 Update (Developer preview). I set a message tone via `Notifications + Actions` > Messaging, and tried user specific one. But still ringing that default tone. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still I didn't get the reason, but last week I reverted the OS for cyan update and took developer preview update. Can't find the issue in this build.